# How to upload image in s3 using signed url and ionic camera plugin in Ionic 4

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, amazon-s3, ionic4

I am using ionic native plugin for image upload with s3 signed url. camera plugin generate the base64 format image so i am not able to upload in right format

```
takePhoto() {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
        encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
        correctOrientation: true,
        sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    };

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
        this.img = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
        this.uploadProfile();
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}

uploadProfile() {
    const phone = localStorage.getItem('phone');
    const imageName = phone + '.jpg';
    this.profileService.getPresignedUrl(imageName).subscribe(res => {
        console.log(res.urls[0]);
        this.profileService.uploadProfile(res.urls[0], this.img).subscribe(data => {
            console.log('Successfully Uploaded');
        });
    });
}
```

I am trying these way but store in text format

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit late but I will put an answer here just in case.
Use FILE_URI as your camera.DestinationType.
Then convert the FILE_URI to blob using XMLHttpRequest.

```
takePhoto() {
    const options: CameraOptions = {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
        correctOrientation: true,
        sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    };

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
        this.imageDataToBlob(imageData)
        this.uploadProfile();
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err);
    });
}
```

imageData to blob

```
imageDataToBlob(imageData) {
  let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', imageData);
  xhr.responseType = 'blob';
  xhr.onload = () => {
    let blobImage = xhr.response;
  }
  xhr.send();
}
```

Hope this helps.